# Internet dropping after 5-10 minutes

Tags: wifi

I have a stable wi-fi connection at my house. After 5-10 minutes, I can no longer stay connected to the internet. The dock will show that I"m online and connected to the wifi, but nothing loads. I've tried several different browsers and other applications, which require internet connections and nothing. After a restart, everything will work fine... for 5-10 minutes until I get the exact same problems again.

Comment: Please edit your question with the output of `lshw -c network`.

Comment: Which wifi card do you have ? Execute this command in terminal if you don't know : `lspci | grep "Network"`

Comment: *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: 74:29:af:0c:6b:b5
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be

Answer (score 4):

The driver of your wifi card is problematic (almost all of Realtek are)
you can try this driver https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new

This way:

```
# Make sure you have the needed tools
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git

# Close the driver
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git

# Enter in the driver directory
cd rtlwifi_new

# Compile
make sudo

# Install
make install

# And finally, reboot
sudo reboot
```

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2261702

Comment: Great, thanks! I'm working on this now. I notice it made a new folder "rtlwifi_new". It made the folder in the personal folder I happened to be in when i started the terminal - /home/myusername/games. Can I move this folder? Should this folder be in my personal folder?

Comment: The folder contains the source code for the driver. Once you run `make install` it will move the compiled driver to the appropriate place on your system and the folder is no longer required.

Comment: It worked perfectly.  Thank you very much for the helpful information.  I'll delete the folder when I get home.

Comment: I'm glad to help you, you can accept the answer, that way if someone else has the same problem can find the solution easily.

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same problem with the same Wi-Fi card, execute the following command in a terminal:

`echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf`

The issue is the driver going to sleep. This command prevents it by disabling power saving.